# img src provided by javascript - how to?

Tags: javascript, retina.js

I already try to google but I had no luck.

How can I make retina.js work with image source provided by other javascript file?

I'm working in someone else's code where the pictures grid is provided by a javascript file. the thumbs are working with retina.js, but the large images when I click the thumbs don't.

In the portfolio.html I have this code:

```
<div class="portfolio">      
   <div id="portfolio"></div>
</div>
```

And It is triggered by

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themes.js"></script>`

Inside themes.js I have this:

```
$(function(){
$("#portfolio").elastic_grid({
    'filterEffect': 'popup', // moveup, scaleup, fallperspective, fly, flip, helix , popup
    'hoverDirection': true,
    'hoverDelay': 0,
    'hoverInverse': false,
    'expandingSpeed': 500,
    'expandingHeight': 500,
    'items' :
    [
        {
            'title'         : 'Logo',
            'description'   : 'Redesign de logo para Medicina Legalis.',
            'thumbnail'     : ['img/folio/thumb/logo_med_legalis.jpg'],
            'large'         : ['img/folio/large/logo_med_legalis.jpg'],
            'button_list'   :
            [
                { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : '#' },

            ],
            'tags'          : ['logo']
        },
    ]
});   });
```

When I open portfolio.html in firefox, retina.js is working on the thumbs. If I analyze in firebug I can see that the thumb has been changed for @2x but the large didn't:

```
<img width="460" height="330" src="img/folio/thumb/logo_med_legalis@2x.jpg" data-largesrc="img/folio/large/logo_med_legalis.jpg">
```

After click the thumb, some javascript that I cold not find yet takes the data-largesrc and generates:

```
<img src="img/folio/large/logo_med_legalis.jpg" style="display: inline;">
```

Well here we are. The retina.js works when rendering the page, Is there any way to make it work on click event for this specific case?

I cold write logo_med_legalis@2x.jpg in the themes.js for the 'large' image but this way non retina users will also render a larger image file in their browser.

Thanks!

Comment: You could load the retina.js script after you run themes.js. [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) might help

Comment: Good one! This also improved my page load. But retina.js after themes.js only worked on Chrome. In Firefox and Safari still the same.